Select one value column from many in a pivot query
I have a table in SQL Server that has rows as follows:



ID (int)
Name (varchar)
IsEnabled (int)
ObjectName (varchar)
PropertyName  (varchar)
PropertyValueString  (varchar)
PropertyValueInt




1
Rule01
1
MyObject
NULL
NULL
NULL


2
Rule02
1
MyObject
NULL
NULL
NULL


3
Rule03
1
MyObject
NULL
NULL
NULL


4
Rule04
1
MyObject
NULL
NULL
NULL


5
Rule05
1
MyObject
NULL
NULL
NULL


6
Prop01
0
MyObject
Prop01
$
NULL


7
Prop02
0
MyObject
Prop02
NULL
45



I wrote this stored procedure that dynamically pivots the rows as columns based on the ObjectName parameter passed in:
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT 
    @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(Name) + ',' 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Name 
     FROM ItemsTable 
     WHERE LOWER(ObjectName) = LOWER(@objectName)  
     GROUP BY Name) AS tmp

SELECT @cols = SUBSTRING(@cols, 0, LEN(@cols))

SET @query = 
'SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT  
      [Name]      
      ,CAST([IsEnabled] AS VARCHAR(50)) as [ValueColumn]  
      ,[ObjectName]           
      FROM ItemsTable 
    UNION
        SELECT  
      [Name]      
      ,[PropertyValueString]    as [ValueColumn]  
      ,[ObjectName]           
      FROM ItemsTable 
    UNION
        SELECT  
      [Name]      
      ,CAST([PropertyValueInt] AS VARCHAR(50))  as [ValueColumn]  
      ,[ObjectName]           
      FROM ItemsTable 
) src
pivot 
(
    max(ValueColumn) for Name in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'

One of the values being returned is incorrect, specifically for Prop01. I am expecting a '$' to be returned but am getting a 0.
How do I fix this error?

Please write meaningful titles, as directed to in [ask]; your title is just 3 tags which is what the tags are for.

Also, you ask three questions here; questions should contain one question. If you have several questions, ask several distinct questions.

Well, the character '0' sorts higher than '$', so '0' is correct for the given logic. If you want to treat IsEnabled = 0 as insignificant, perhaps you want NULLIF([IsEnabled], 0) in the first part of your union. You might want similar for your PropertyValueInt column. See this db<>fiddle.

Or id you want the zero to be treated as an empty string (instead of null) you can try ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF([IsEnabled], 0) AS VARCHAR(50)), '''') (with quotes doubled for the dynamic SQL string).

"Query is returning an incorrect value" No, you are writing the query wrong that is returning the wrong value.

Another approach is to drop the UNION and use a CROSS APPLY to select the appropriate source value for each row - ...FROM ItemsTable CROSS APPLY (SELECT COALESCE(PropertyValueString, CAST(PropertyValueInt AS VARCHAR(50)), CAST(IsEnabled AS VARCHAR(50))) AS ValueColumn) V .... This assumes that no more than one PropertyValue* column will be non-null per row, and IsEnabled applies only if all property values are null. See this db<>fiddle. You can further tweak the logic as needed.

@TN: I am still tweaking the table, but second assumption can be safely made(IsEnabled applies only if all property values are null). The first assumption can be made, for now. Could you post your solution as an answer?

Well, the character '0' sorts higher than '$', so '0' is correct for the given logic. If you want to treat IsEnabled = 0 as insignificant, perhaps you want NULLIF([IsEnabled], 0) in the first part of your union. You might want similar for your PropertyValueInt column.
Or if you want the zero to be treated as an empty string (instead of null) you can try ISNULL(CAST(NULLIF([IsEnabled], 0) AS VARCHAR(50)), '''') (with quotes doubled for the dynamic SQL string).
Another approach is to drop the UNION and use a CROSS APPLY to select the appropriate source value for each row.
SET @query = 
'SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT  
        I.Name
        ,V.ValueColumn
        ,I.ObjectName
    FROM ItemsTable I
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT COALESCE(
            I.PropertyValueString,
            CAST(I.PropertyValueInt AS VARCHAR(50)),
            CAST(I.IsEnabled AS VARCHAR(50))
            ) AS ValueColumn
    ) V
) src
pivot
(
    max(ValueColumn) for Name in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'

This assumes that no more than one PropertyValue* column will be non-null per row, and IsEnabled applies only if all property values are null. You can further tweak the logic as needed.
See this db<>fiddle.

Another option, without using PIVOT is:
SELECT
  ObjectName,
  MAX(PropertyName) as Prop01,
  MAX(PropertyValueString) as Prop02,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Name='Rule01' THEN IsEnabled ELSE 0 END) as Rule01,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Name='Rule02' THEN IsEnabled ELSE 0 END) as Rule02,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Name='Rule03' THEN IsEnabled ELSE 0 END) as Rule03,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Name='Rule04' THEN IsEnabled ELSE 0 END) as Rule04,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Name='Rule05' THEN IsEnabled ELSE 0 END) as Rule05
FROM itemsTable
GROUP BY ObjectName

see: DBFIDDLE
P.S.  SUM(), or MAX(), can be changed to another aggregate function is needed.
